# SQL XML - Return result set

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, select

I have the following SQL Query:

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<IDs><ID>1</ID><ID>2</ID></IDs>'

SELECT @x.query('/IDs/ID') as ID
```

This returns the following result:

```
ID
--------------------
<ID>1</ID><ID>2</ID>
```

How can I instead get this to return:

```
ID
--
1
2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this code instead:

```
declare @x xml
set @x = '<IDs><ID>1</ID><ID>2</ID></IDs>'

SELECT ID.value('.', 'int') AS ID
FROM @x.nodes('/IDs/ID') as IDS(ID)
```

Comment: +2 if I could. I still can't get my head wrapped around XML in SQLServer.